# Kendo UI flip effect in Internet Explorer shows back too soon

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kendo-ui, effect, flip

I'm developing a BI dashboard for a business app using the JavaScript Kendo UI version v2014.1.416, but I'm having a problem with some visuals in IE11.

I want to point out that due to real-world constraints, **running IE11 is for all intents and purposes set in stone**. The Kendo version number is somewhat easier to deal with, but still no picnic.

Specifically, I use the kendo.fx.flip() function to display a flip card. The card flips ok, but the "back of the card" is rendered before the flip animation starts. In contrast, the same effect in Chrome and Firefox plays out as it should, i.e., the back is shown halfway(-ish) through the animation.

I had a look at the API reference page for the flip effect, at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/effects/flip. As it turns out, the reference page example exhibits the same behavior in IE11.

I'm guessing the effect uses the CSS3 flip function under the hood (haven't looked yet though) and this seems to be somewhat of a general problem given the amount of questions regarding flip in IE.

My question is twofold:

1) Is there a way to "fix" the animation specifically for IE, using the provided version of Kendo and/or using regular CSS?

2) Is this effect fixed for IE in later Kendo versions, in spite of the behavior on the API reference page?

Answer (score 0):

I could only get this to look nice by setting a large no-repeat fixed background image on both 'sides' (made out of a simple white png).